# javascript Angularjs get single value from array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs, scope

I'm quite new to angularjs and somehow theres something I can't make a workaround.

Its getting a single value from a json array and then placing it in a scope variable. Lets say just got an array from a php query which looks like this (printed view):

```
array(
[name]   => John Doe,
[age]    => 29,
[gender] =>male);
```

And then it is added through this scope variable:

```
$scope.profile = response.data;
```

How can I pick a single a value from that array and then place it separate scope variables?

```
$scope.name; $scope.age; $scope.gender;
```

Comment: try `response.data.name` or `response.data['name']`  and assign it to `$scope.name`

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work. Looks like I need to transfer it to object from json first.

Comment: Parse json object in javascript or try to send php data in json_encoded format

Comment: use this method for parsing json `JSON.parse(response);`  and store it in variable

Comment: I tried this:

$scope.profile = JSON.parse(response); and even $scope.profile = JSON.parse(response.data); but its not returning anything.

Comment: try to `console.log(response)` and show me the data

Comment: I don't know what I'm seeing but all I can see here is the array in data

Comment: can you told me what it look like?

Comment: the data looks like this:

Array(
[name]   => John Doe,
[age]    => 29,
[gender] =>male);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send your data back from your PHP using [**`json_encode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
return json_encode($array);
```

which will then give you

```
object {
 name: 'John Doe',
 age: '29',
 gender: 'male'
}
```

And you can then access it using:

```
$scope.profile = response.data;
//
$scope.name   = $scope.profile.name;
$scope.age    = $scope.profile.age;
$scope.gender = $scope.profile.gender;
```

---

**Example:**

```js
var app = angular.module('someApp', [])
  .controller('someCtrl', function ($scope) {
    
    var object = {
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: '29',
      gender: 'male'
    };

    $scope.profile = object;
    
    $scope.name   = $scope.profile.name;
    $scope.age    = $scope.profile.age;
    $scope.gender = $scope.profile.gender;
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="someApp" ng-controller="someCtrl">{{name}}, {{age}}, {{gender}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.name = response.data.name;
$scope.age = response.data.age;
$scope.gender = response.data.gender;
```

This should add them to the `$scope`.

Make sure that the elements are in an object, not JSON string anymore.

Or if you stay with the other one you already have:

```
$scope.name = $scope.profile.name;
$scope.age = $scope.profile.age;
$scope.gender = $scope.profile.gender;
```

Comment: the elements are still on JSON string. How can I transfer it first?

Comment: JSON.parse(stringToParse);

Comment: i tried it, but its not working. its nor returning anything.